# Returning HTML fragments with JsonView in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, json

I'm using Cake 2.1, and with it comes the new [JsonView](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-2-1.html#jsonview). What I'd like to do is POST to a method in my controller and render an html fragment so that I can return it as a value in json.

Previously I'd do something like this:

```
public function ajaxSubmit() {
    if (!$this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->redirect('/');
    } else {
        $this->autoRender = $this->layout = false;

        $message = 'Please enter a message';
        $this->set('message');
        $errorFragment = $this->render('/Elements/errors/flash_error');
        $toReturn = array('errorFragment' => $errorFragment);
        return json_encode($toReturn);
    }
}
```

Which only sends back the html fragment of that particular `flash_error` element such that I can't have multiple `key => values` being sent back in a standard json object. I want to be able to send both html fragments and just plain text as json.

So my question really is, how can I render an HTML element and set it with a (key=>value pair) to be sent back as json from my controller using the JsonView that Cake 2.1 provides? I already have set in my routes file `Router::parseExtensions('json');` and I'm including the `RequestHandler` component inside of my AppController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need a separate action for AJAX when using data views. Use can use the same action as your non AJAX submit.

However assuming that you wish to use a different action for AJAX because I don't know what your other action looks like, you can write something like this in `app/View/ControllerName/json/ajaxSubmit.ctp`.

```
<?php
$errorFragment = $this->element('errors/flash_error');
$toReturn = array('errorFragment' => $errorFragment);
echo json_encode($toReturn);
```

Then change your action to this

```
public function ajaxSubmit() {
    if (!$this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->redirect('/');
    } else {
        $message = 'Please enter a message';
        $this->set('message');
    }
}
```

See "[Using a data view with view files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-a-data-view-with-view-files)" in the documentation.

Comment: Hmm thanks. That seems to work, but it also seems awfully clunky. What is the point of ajaxSubmit.ctp anyway? It seems like the only reason it exists is to be able to call that `flash_error` element...

Comment: That is why you might be better off using the same action for AJAX and normal submit.
Assuming your normal submit does the same thing then you could reduce that action to 2 lines of code.

Comment: The purpose of using RequestHandler and parseExtensions is that it will automatically switch to the data view. That is why you need ajaxSubmit.ctp. If you send me a more complete example of what you want to do then I can help a bit more.

Comment: Essentially I just wanted to validate a submission within my model from my controller and pass back an html fragment of my flash error element if it didn't pass any validation. Then I'd just populate that html fragment into the page, instead of having to hide a div and then populate it with the responseText. I can do this normally, but it gets a little trickier finding the proper way to do it with ajax.